# JAGS Runtime Error: Cannot insert node into X[ ]. Dimension Mismatch

Tags: r, bayesian, jags

I'm trying to add a bit of code to a data-augmentation capture-recapture model and am coming up with some errors I haven't encountered before. In short, I want to estimate a series of survivorship phases that each last more than a single time interval. I want the model to estimate the length of each survivorship phase and use that to improve the capture recapture model. I tried and failed with a few different approaches, and am now trying to accomplish this using a switching state array for the survivorship phases:

```
for (t in 1:(n.occasions-1)){

phi1switch[t] ~ dunif(0,1)  
phi2switch[t] ~ dunif(0,1)   
phi3switch[t] ~ dunif(0,1)   
phi4switch[t] ~ dunif(0,1)

psphi[1,t,1] <- 1-phi1switch[t]
psphi[1,t,2] <- phi1switch[t]
psphi[1,t,3] <- 0
psphi[1,t,4] <- 0
psphi[1,t,5] <- 0

psphi[2,t,1] <- 0
psphi[2,t,2] <- 1-phi2switch[t]
psphi[2,t,3] <- phi2switch[t]
psphi[2,t,4] <- 0
psphi[2,t,5] <- 0

psphi[3,t,1] <- 0
psphi[3,t,2] <- 0
psphi[3,t,3] <- 1-phi3switch[t]
psphi[3,t,4] <- phi3switch[t]
psphi[3,t,5] <- 0

psphi[4,t,1] <- 0
psphi[4,t,2] <- 0
psphi[4,t,3] <- 0
psphi[4,t,4] <- 1-phi4switch[t]
psphi[4,t,5] <- phi4switch[t]

psphi[5,t,1] <- 0
psphi[5,t,2] <- 0
psphi[5,t,3] <- 0
psphi[5,t,4] <- 0
psphi[5,t,5] <- 1
}
```

So this creates a [5,t,5] array where the survivorship state can only switch to the subsequent state and not backwards (e.g. 1 to 2, 4 to 5, but not 4 to 3). Now I create a vector where the survivorship state is defined:

```
PhiState[1] <- 1  

for (t in 2:(n.occasions-1)){
# State process: draw PhiState(t) given PhiState(t-1)
PhiState[t] ~ dcat(psphi[PhiState[t-1], t-1,])
}
```

We start in state 1 always, and then take a categorical draw at each time step 't' for remaining in the current state or moving on to the next one given the probabilities within the array. I want a maximum of 5 states (assuming that the model will be able to functionally produce fewer by estimating the probability of moving from state 3 to 4 and onwards near 0, or making the survivorship value of subsequent states the same or similar if they belong to the same survivorship value in reality). So I create 5 hierarchical survival probabilities:

```
for (a in 1:5){
mean.phi[a] ~ dunif(0,1)
phi.tau[a] <- pow(phi_sigma[a],-2)
phi.sigma[a] ~ dunif(0,20)
}
```

Now this next step is where the errors start. Now that I've assigned values 1-5 to my PhiState vector it should look something like this:

```
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 5
```

or maybe

```
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2
```

and I now want to assign a mean.phi[] to my actual phi[] term, which feeds into the model:

```
for(t in 1:(n.occasions-1)){
phi[t] ~ dnorm(mean.phi[PhiState[t]],phi.tau[PhiState[t]])
}
```

However, when I try to run this I get the following error:

```
Error in jags.model(model.file, data = data, inits = init.values, n.chains = n.chains,  : 
  RUNTIME ERROR:
Cannot insert node into mean.phi[1:5]. Dimension mismatch
```

It's worth noting that the model works just fine when I use the following phi[] determinations:

```
phi[t] ~ dunif(0,1) #estimate independent annual phi's
```

or

```
phi[t] ~ dnorm(mean.phi,phi_tau) #estimate hierarchical phi's from a single mean.phi
```

or

```
#Set fixed survial periods (this works the best, but I don't want to have to tell it when 
#the periods start/end and how many there are, hence the current exercise):
for (a in 1:21){
surv[a] ~ dnorm(mean.phi1,phi1_tau)
}

for (b in 22:30){
surv[b] ~ dnorm(mean.phi2,phi2_tau)
}

for (t in 1:(n.occasions-1)){
phi[t] <- surv[t]
}
```

I did read this post: https://sourceforge.net/p/mcmc-jags/discussion/610037/thread/36c48f25/

but I don't see where I'm redefining variables in this case... Any help fixing this or advice on a better approach would be most welcome!

Many thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused as to what are your actual data (the `phi[t]`?), but the following might give you a starting point:

```
nt <- 29
nstate <- 5
M <- function() {
  phi_state[1] <- 1
  for (t in 2:nt) {
    up[t-1] ~ dbern(p[t-1])
    p[t-1] <- ifelse(phi_state[t-1]==nstate, 0, p_[t-1])
    p_[t-1] ~ dunif(0, 1)
    phi_state[t] <- phi_state[t-1] + equals(up[t-1], 1)
  }
  for (k in 1:nstate) {
    mean_phi[k] ~ dunif(0, 1)
    phi_sigma[k] ~ dunif(0, 20)
  }
  for(t in 1:(nt-1)){
    phi[t] ~ dnorm(mean_phi[phi_state[t]], phi_sigma[phi_state[t]]^-2)
  }
}

library(R2jags)
fit <- jags(list(nt=nt, nstate=nstate), NULL, 
            c('phi_state', 'phi', 'mean_phi', 'phi_sigma', 'p'), 
            M, DIC=FALSE)
```

Note that above, `p` is a vector of probabilities of moving up to the next (adjacent) state.